# Do I need to create index for the column when using it in update statement?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgresql11 which has a `userId` as a column. And it is not primary key in the table.
I need to perform below update statement on the table.

`update entity set name='xxxx' where userId = 'yyy`.

The `userId` is in the `where` condition but I don't know whether I should create an index for `userId`. Will it improve performance? If yes, how can I specify index in the `update` statement?

Comment: *I don't know whether I should create an index* You may, but not must.

Answer (score 4):

Indexes are meant to improve performance of predicates used in `WHERE`, `JOIN`, and `HAVING` clauses for any type of query. So yes having an index on `userId` theoretically *can* improve performance of your `UPDATE` example query.

After you create the index you don't need to specify it in your query, PostgreSQL will automatically use it if its engine thinks it'll help the query performance.